# angularjs error witg ng-options

Tags: angularjs, html-select, ng-options

I am trying this code in angularJs:

```
app.controller('controlselect', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.provinces = [];
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: './api.php?accion=provinces'
        }).success(function (result) {
        $scope.provinces = result;
    });
```

And this the html to show this:

```
<select ng-model="province.idprovince" data-ng-options="province.idprovince as province.province for province in provinces"></select>
```

Object's example filled in:

```
provinces:
[ {provinceid: '1', province: 'Option A'}, {provinceid: '2', province: 'Option B'}, {provinceid: '3', province: 'Option C'} ]
```

If I like to show an ng-repeat="province in provinces" this works good, but when I Try the ng-options on select no work.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: can u create jsfiddle link

Comment: Whether ``province.idprovince`` value is set ??

Comment: Your example object is not a valid JavaScript object.

Comment: @muenchdo Yes, is an invalid object, I am seeing it with the Angular extension on Chrome and I type manually this, but is a valid object

Comment: @SameerK idprovince have a number (1,2,3,4,5,...) and provinec have a value text (Madrid, Leon, Valladolid, ...)

Comment: If I Try with object:

 $scope.provinces =
 [
      {provinceid: '1', province: 'Option A'},
      {provinceid: '2', province: 'Option B'},
      {provinceid: '3', province: 'Option C'}
   ];

Works perfect, but when I like to get with the HTTP CALL no works.

Any idea?

Comment: I think http call load after html tag and not load the data in select but i don't have idea to load first data and after html tag select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example http://dojo.telerik.com/ayimI
You have do transformation for your json array
as

```
$scope.provinces = [{"idprovince": "1", "province": "name"}];
```

Hope this mat help you.

Comment: When i load the object work, but when i load object with http get, no work

Comment: can you make change in dojo with same to reproduce or try using $scope.$apply(); after getting response

Comment: When I type $scople.apply(); after get data I get this error: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.11/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: @David try using $timeout(function(){ }, 0);